# view doesn't work in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am newbie for laravel and doing my first project called blog. For post article i can fetch data but I am trying to display reader's comment in the index page just below the article by fetching from database but it gives error(For info,I have already inserted a row from `xammp` just to fetch).Here is the code for `PostController.php`

```
public function index()
{
    //$show = Post::all();
    $show = Post::orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(1);
   return view('pages/blog')->with('post',$show);
}


public function comment()
{
    $show = readerComment::all();
    return view('pages/blog')->with('commentShow',$show);
}
```

In index pages or blog.blade.php

```
@if(count($post)>0)
                            @foreach($post as $article)
                                <div class = "row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <h3 class="text-center">{{$article->title}}</h2>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <p>{!!$article->article!!}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            <!-- Comment section -->
                            <div class = "comment">
                                <h3>Comments</h3>

                                @foreach($commentShow as $commShow)
                                    <div class = "row">
                                        <div class = "col-md-12">
                                        <p>{{$commShow->comment}}</p>
                                        <p>{{$commShow->name}}</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                @endforeach

                            </div>
```

And in web route

```
 Route::resource('posts','PostController');
 Route::get('/','PostController@comment');
```

I get error as

```
Undefined variable: post (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\blogging\resources\views\pages\blog.blade.php)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: you are doing a lot of things wrong. I would highly suggest learning some basic fundamentals before trying to move forward. laracasts.com has a pretty great free video course to help you get a solid grasp of the basics

Comment: When you use the `->with()` method the first parameter passed to it is the name of the variable available on the view.  So for the comment part you make this call `->with('commentShow',$show);` yet in your view you try and access it via `$post`.  Change this line `@foreach($post as $commShow)` to `@foreach($commentShow as $commShow)`

Comment: Yeeooow  i tried that too but gives me same error, undefined variable post, but if i don't run comment function, it works as normal that displays post but doesn't  display comment,

Comment: See answer below

Answer (score 0):

Do it like that,

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(1);
   return view('pages.blog',compact('posts'));
}
```

Comment: It didn't work, gave same error, undefined variable: post . but when i don't run comment function or cut it off then post article works as normal.

Comment: In your view change `$post`  `@foreach($post as $commShow)` to `$commentShow` and also `@if(count($post)>0)` to `@if(!empty($post))`

Comment: It didn't give any error but when i run "blog.localhost/" , it displays nothing. But when i run "blog.localhost/posts", it displays posts but no comments whatsoever

Answer (score 0):

You're blade looks good without error, but let's try this view..

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
                    @if(count($post)>0)
                        @foreach($post as $article)
                            <div class = "row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <h3 class="text-center">{{$article->title}}</h2>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <p>{!!$article->article!!}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        <!-- Comment section -->
                        <div class = "comment">
                            <h3>Comments</h3>

                            @foreach($post as $commShow)
                                <div class = "row">
                                    <div class = "col-md-12">
                                    <p>{{$commShow->comment}}</p>
                                    <p>{{$commShow->name}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            @endforeach

                    </div>@endsection
```

Comment: Sorry, Isn't it same one i did? doesn't look any difference to mine.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to this:

> When you use the `->with()` method the first parameter passed to it is
>   the name of the variable available on the view. So for the comment
>   part you make this call `->with('commentShow',$show);` yet in your view
>   you try and access it via `$post`. Change this line `@foreach($post as
>   $commShow)` to `@foreach($commentShow as $commShow)`

change you view code to this: (please note the changed variable name in second `@foreach`)

```
@if(isset($post) && !empty($post)) 
@foreach($post as $article)
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3 class="text-center">{{$article->title}}</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <p>{!!$article->article!!}</p>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
@endif

@if(isset($commentShow) && !empty($commentShow)) 
<!-- Comment section -->
<div class="comment">
    <h3>Comments</h3>

    @foreach($commentShow as $commShow)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>{{$commShow->comment}}</p>
            <p>{{$commShow->name}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
@endif
```

Comment: Hey,I did what you said and still giving me same error=> undefined variable post,

Answer (score 0):

Here you are defining your Eloquent Collection of models to be `$commentShow`:

```
return view('pages/blog')->with('commentShow',$show);
```

In your view, you are using the variable `$post`.
You need to change one of them to match the other.

Comment: I think i changed what you said. I guess i am trying to pass two variables to view to display it, one for post and other one for comment from same controller which is why its not working.